# Export oracle database tables

Tags: oracle, database-administration

i am working on  a large database ,how do i Export some database tables without  having dba  privileges .do i have to copy the structures of the tables and using spool command to get the data in a text file then create the tables and inserting data from the text file?

Comment: Have you tried export data pump?

Answer (score 2):

One of the methods would be to install Oracle SQL Developer and export the required table structures and data using the wizard.

Here is the link to a tutorial which can guide you if you go with this option.

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm

A second option would be to use SQL Loader to load data in your target tables. But for that you will have to first create the data structures on your target schema and spool the data from your source tables in CSV (comma separated values) or any other eligible format.

Here is a link for SQL Loader.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm

A third option would be that you create the table structures on the target schema and generate the insert statements from the source schema using a script. Here is a link to such an example.

https://pandazen.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/generate-insert-statement-script-to-extract-data-from-oracle-table/

I would recommend going with the SQL Developer option since it is relatively simple.

Comment: @OP - Keep in mind that if you import data from SQL Developer, you will get table/column names surrounded by `double quotes`. If you reimport it, then the table and column names will be literal. So make sure to remove all `double quotes` after importing from SQL developer

Comment: I tried a new technique which is to spool the data from the source tables with a select statement, the select statement has the all the text required for insert statement then i used the output file for inserting the data. for example : select ||'insert into new_table values'|| my_column from my_table;